# Photo-Tagging implementing Face Detection in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, face-detection

I am working on an android application that tags photo on image, which using the Face Detection. This application just like tag photo on Facebook after Facebook detected the faces in a photo.

My main problem is, I do not know how to return the faceID and do the image tagging and I did a lot of trying, but did not success.  Here is my Face Detection coding.

```
package com.application.nurfatinahjannah.muka;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.*;
import com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.contract.*;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.io.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.provider.*;
```

public class CameraActivity extends Second {

```
ImageButton takephoto;

private FaceServiceClient faceServiceClient =
        new FaceServiceRestClient("09eec022662e429ba6f2df36454ff120");

private final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
private ProgressDialog detectionProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    takephoto  = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.takephoto);

    takephoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent gallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            gallIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallIntent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });

    detectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            detectAndFrame(bitmap);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
private void detectAndFrame(final Bitmap imageBitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream =
            new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

    AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Face[]> detectTask = new AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Face[]>()
    {
                @Override
                protected Face[] doInBackground(InputStream... params) {
                    try {
                        publishProgress("Detecting...");
                        Face[] result = faceServiceClient.detect(
                                params[0],
                                true ,         // returnFaceId
                                false,        // returnFaceLandmarks
                                null           // returnFaceAttributes: a string like "age, gender"
                        );
                        if (result == null)
                        {
                            publishProgress("Detection Finished. Nothing detected");
                            return null;
                        }
                        publishProgress(
                                String.format("Detection Finished. %d face(s) detected",
                                        result.length));
                        return result;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        publishProgress("Detection failed");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    detectionProgressDialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                    detectionProgressDialog.setMessage(progress[0]);
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Face[] result) {
                    detectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (result == null) return;
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(drawFaceRectanglesOnBitmap(imageBitmap, result));
                    imageBitmap.recycle();
                }

            };


    detectTask.execute(inputStream);
}
private static Bitmap drawFaceRectanglesOnBitmap(Bitmap originalBitmap, Face[] faces) {
    Bitmap bitmap = originalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    int stokeWidth = 2;
    paint.setStrokeWidth(stokeWidth);
    if (faces != null) {
        for (Face face : faces) {
            FaceRectangle faceRectangle = face.faceRectangle;
            canvas.drawRect(
                    faceRectangle.left,
                    faceRectangle.top,
                    faceRectangle.left + faceRectangle.width,
                    faceRectangle.top + faceRectangle.height,
                    paint);
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

Comment: do you solved this?